# Occurring empty lines in the CSV file while converting PDF document to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, tabula-py

I am new to python. I have an issue while converting `PDf` file into `CSV` format. I have used `tabula` for converting my PDF file into `CSV`. but, while converting PDF into `CSV` I am facing the occurrence of empty lines in the `CSV` file

sample pdf file to need to be converted
[sample pdf format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xjxm.png)

This is what i have tried,

```
pdf_path = "/home/niranjan/code/html_spikes/statewise/cin/pdfreader/Manipur_company_1.pdf"

doc = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path,pages = 'all')
tabula.convert_into(pdf_path,"manipur.csv", output_format = "csv", pages = 'all')
print(doc)
```

This is the result looks like
[converted CSV format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIBE3.png)

The Result I was expecting
[Expected CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wezfV.png)

the converted CSV file gives some cells as empty but I need perfect row order. I can't able to figure-out how to do it.

Anyone suggest better way to do it

Comment: You might want to give a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may check [layout parsing](https://layout-parser.github.io/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this..
Here is the code

```
for row in reader:
    name = " "
    if not row[0]:
       name = row[1]
       for row in reader:
           full_name = name+ " " + row[1] 
           break
       row[1] = full_name
```